# Exponential decay of the gradient if the function itself and the Laplacian have exponential decay

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice continously differentiable. For $n=1$ one can prove using Taylors formula that we have
$$ \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq R} \vert f'(x) \vert \leq 2\left( \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq R+1} \vert f(x) \vert \right) +  \left( \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq R+1} \vert f''(x) \vert \right) $$
From this we can show that if $f$ and $f''$ have exponential decay, then so does $f'$. My question is, whether this is still true in higher dimension in the following version

> Is the following statement true: If $f$ and $\Delta f$ have exponential decay, then $\nabla f$ has exponential decay as well (I guess that it holds true if we have the full Hessian instead of just the Laplacian using again Taylor's theorem).

Anyway, I would already be happy to know the answer for $n=3$ (also if you want to assume another continuous derivative or two, be my guest. Even assuming $f$ to be smooth would be fine for me).

Even the radial case would be fine. However, even there I don't see how to do it. Changing to spherical coordinates we get $g: [0; \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \vert g (r) \vert , \vert g''(r) + \frac{2}{r} g'(r) \vert \leq D e^{-C r} $$
and we want to conclude that the same holds true for $g$.

Comment: this should be relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo–Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for the link, but it seems to me that this inequality uses the full second derivative and not only the Laplacian.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Indeed you are right. We also have a version as I need it https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214937/gagliardo-nirenberg-inequality-for-the-laplacian/214946

Comment: Great, sorry I'm not fluent enough to have found the one you needed / type it into an answer!

Comment: @CalvinKhor You got me on the right track. Thanks you so much and Happy Easter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CalvinKhor I found the following mathoverflow answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214937/gagliardo-nirenberg-inequality-for-the-laplacian/214946 where they show for every $n$ there exists a constant $c$ such that for any $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$ \Vert  \nabla f \Vert_{L^\infty(B_1)} \leq C (\Vert \Delta f \Vert_{L^\infty(B_2)} + \Vert f \Vert_{L^\infty(B_2)}) $$
Which allows us to obtain the exponential decay of $\nabla f$ given that $f$ and $\Delta f$ decay exponentially.